# Facebook login issues (OAuth2)

Tags: javascript, facebook, oauth-2.0

I have started to receive the following error:

```
 OAuth2 specification states that 'perms' should now be called 'scope'.  Please update.
```

, but I get this error on http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js
How to fix this, because it's the only way to login on my site.
Thanks!

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/525/

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.init/

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/